# How to change values in cells of datatable using c# script

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have made a DataTable in a c# script in visual studio using a foreach loop using information from an excel file which I read in. The table looks like this: [image: screenshot of table].

Now, after I made the table, I want to adjust values in the columns depending on values on other columns. For example, I want the ABC_0003_10 value in the first column to change to ABC_0003_r010 (so 10 has to change to the value of the third column) if certain criteria are met.

Basically I want to use the datatable as a matrix in my workspace as in, for example, R or matlab. Does anyone know how to do this in a c# script in visual studio?

Comment: Use a `foreach`-loop. Tbh i don't understand the question or what didn't work.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do but would you mind sharing some code of what you've tried so far?

I can't really write your code but I can help you if you show me to point out what's wrong with it.

Comment: But how can I then insert the condition that if two values in different rows of the VariableColumnCode are the same, a cell in the VariableGroup column changes as mentioned above?

Comment: I tried to do it in the foreach loop where I made the entire table using this code:                                         
    if (ssColumn[0] == '0')
    {
        newRow2["VariableGroup"] = CheckCode + "_" + ssColumn.Substring(2, 2);
    }

Comment: However, this is extremely inefficient since i need to make the entire table again if I want to add another condition. Therefore, I want to do it with a foreach loop after I made the table, but I don't really know how to